# CPP std::thread attempt to use a deleted function

Tags: c++, xcode, multithreading, c++11

First of all, I want to say that i already made researches on the subject, but nothing relevant...

([Error creating std::thread on Mac OS X with clang: "attempt to use a deleted function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308908/error-creating-stdthread-on-mac-os-x-with-clang-attempt-to-use-a-deleted-fun))

([Xcode 7: C++ threads ERROR: Attempting to use a deleted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910424/xcode-7-c-threads-error-attempting-to-use-a-deleted-function))

([xcode - "attempt to use a deleted function" - what does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080102/xcode-attempt-to-use-a-deleted-function-what-does-that-mean))

And here's my issue...:

clang error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:347:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
__invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
```

And that's my code:

```
bool GenAI::loadAIs()
{
    bool ret = true;

    if (_nbThread > 1)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _nbThread; ++i)
            threads.push_back(std::thread(static_cast<void (GenAI::*)(bool &, unsigned int)>(&GenAI::loadAIs), this, ret, i));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _nbThread; ++i)
            threads[i].join();
    }
    else
        loadAIs(ret, 0);
    return ret;
}

// And the prototype of the function that i try to call
void GenAI::loadAIs(bool & ret, unsigned int iThread);
```

If some one could help me that'd be really helpful ! :)

Regards ;)

Comment: It should be something like `std::ref(ret)`, and you should have one `bool` by `thread` or use `std::atomic<bool>`...

Comment: Thanks you very much, it was the std::ref(ret) that didnt compile... If you write it as an answer i'll be able to close this ticket :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass reference to thread, you have to use `std::reference_wrapper`, that you can obtain with `std::ref`. So your code becomes:

```
threads.emplace_back(static_cast<void (GenAI::*)(bool &, unsigned int)>(&GenAI::loadAIs),
                     this,
                     std::ref(ret),
                     i));
```

Note:
  `bool ret` should probably be `std::atomic<bool> ret`, or should should have one `bool` by thread. Else you may have concurrent access on `ret`.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! :) But it still works with vector::push_back();

Comment: I used `emplace_back` as it makes shorter line (and avoid one (elided?) move).

Answer (score 0):

The deleted function that it is complaining about is a deleted copy constructor for const thread.

For the deleted function problem, you can use:

```
threads.emplace_back(
```

Instead of:

```
threads.push_back(
```

What the commenter also referred to is that the function is creating  more than one thread and passing to them a reference to the same boolean return variable.

It will crash if you don't use atomic_bool and even if you do, they will all report back to the same memory location, making the function miss the notification if one of them returns false.

Comment: that's why i write this as first argument. And i sent the function address to std::thread. And I know it can works with non-static function member

Comment: I have an other part of my code that I compiled some weeks ago and I did call non-static member function with std::thread... I really dont know why it doesnt work... plus it is in the same file...

Comment: I tried to rename the overload with an underscore ahead its name, but nothing changed... I start to think to reboot lol

Comment: I'm only working within one class. Theres no other class. But still strange... I'll reboot (can try it ^^)

Comment: found the answer for the deleted function issue :)

Comment: `push_back` should handle `rvalue` too. With `emplace`, you may remove `std::thread` constructor call.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and your help :) It needed a std::ref(ret)

Answer (score -1):

I would get back to reading. Just use another language - Python!

Or use emplace_back

Vladimir Mikov 4044087744

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).